# How to trigger post to an external web api, immediately after successful payment in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module, opencart-events

I have a bunch of web APIs created using ASP.Net MVC WebApi for any third-party integrations.  Now we need to integrate with one of our partners who has got their platform on OpenCart. I don't know the exact version.

My requirement is to trigger my APIs immediately after the payment gets received (on successful payment).
I am a .Net developer and I don't have any idea about Opencart. But yes, I can manage to code PHP.  Since they don't have developers to do so, so they need a solution from us in the form of some extension or plugin so that they can simply install that.

1. Is there any plugin or module where I can simply add my API URL and its keys and choose the data to expose to my API?
   OR
2. Do I need to create my own extension ?

I need your help to point me in the right direction. Any links or online refenrences will also work.

Comment: You can use OpenCart events system.